# Triple slash in PHP MYSQL result

Tags: php, mysql

I have used `mysql_real_escape_string` to enter info into the database but when I return the info in a query I get `\\\'` in the text. I have made it so that the insert query does not stop at the `'` in a sentance anymore when saving as it used to. It used to stop saving he title of an article halfway through if it contained an apostrophe. That has been fixed but now I get `\\\'` where there is an apostrophe.

Example: `Microsoft\\\'s $15 Windows 8 upgrade offer to run from June 2nd to January 31st, will include free workshops`

My query code to return a list from the database looks like this: (Note that this is an excerpt so does not contain the closing of this loop)

```
<?php

    $q2 = "SELECT * FROM ReadLater WHERE Folder_ID = 0 AND User_ID = $loggedInUser->user_id ORDER BY dt_added DESC";
    $r2 = mysql_query($q2);

    echo "<div id='folderstitleright'>Unread</div>";

    if(mysql_num_rows($r2)>0)
        {
        echo "<ul id='foldersarticlelist'>";
        $sr2=1;
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($r2))

            {

            echo "
               <li class='box'>
```

etc

Any idea how to stop this? I have tested to see if magic quotes are on and they are but with the web host I have no way of turning them (that i have found, there may well be a really complicated way but I haven't found it yet) of and they also say they ignore php flags in the .htaccess file.

I have tried to do a preg_replace of `\\\' to '` but have so far been unsuccessful, from what I have tried of that it breaks the query entirely but I may well be executing it wrong or have it placed in the wrong place in the code above.

Comment: Show how you insert into the database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) with this, just use [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php).

```
$text = str_replace("\\\\\\", "'", $text);
// Use 6 slashes as '\\' is really '\' because '\-' is an escape sequence.
```

Comment: @TheTechBox: What about other possible escaped character combinations?  Better to use [`stripslashes`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php) as suggested in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10788941/623041).

Answer (score 0):

To use the data that's currently in your database, use [`stripslashes`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php) *twice* on what is returned.

However, it would be better to correct what is in the database and to change your `INSERT` script so that no further corrupted data is inserted in the future (probably involves removing a call to [`addslashes`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php) or [`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php)).

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I would ask your web host to disabled magic quotes, if you checkout page http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.magic-quotes-gpc you can read "Warning This feature has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0 and REMOVED as of PHP 5.4.0.".

You cannot disabled it during runtime, so your host must do the changes in the php configuration.
If your host refuses to disable magic quotes, you can create a php function such as "secVar()" which you use instead of "mysql_real_escape_string" in everyone of your mysql queries.

Then your function "secVar" will be:

In case of "magic quotes" activated on the web host:

```
function secVar($var){
    return $var;
}
```

If the "magic quotes" are disabled on the web host:

```
function secVar($var){
    return mysql_real_escape_string($var)
}
```

Doing it this way enables you to quickly update your scripts to secure your variables the day your webhost disables magic quotes or if you change hosts.

You can also take the problem the other way:
Magic quotes are "placed" during runtime, before your script gets exectued. By memory the "magic quotes" are placed on the following arrays of vars: $_REQUEST, $_POST, $_GET, $_FILES and maybe others. 
Knowing that you could 
1. Check if magic quotes are enabled 
2. If so strip all slashes from each vars from each arrays that have been affected by the magic quotes.

One or the other solution should work out for you.

Have fun!